# How to set the loading button on sending the message

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set the text "sending..." with the following code snippets... https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/awesome-chat-messages-box-43788219 Actually, I am creating my chatting system for my web application. can someone please help me to do so...

I tried the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function changeText(submitId){
    var submit = document.getElementById(submitId);
    submit.value = 'Loading...';
    return false;
};
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain it im not understand what are you saying

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is quite vague. You should add more information. Like what code is calling the changeText-method. Where does it get the submitId (is it supposed to be the "Send" button?). Where are you trying to set the "sending..." text?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `innerHTML` instead of `value`

```js
function changeText(submitId){
    var submit = document.getElementById(submitId);
    submit.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
    return false;
};
```

```html
<button onclick="changeText(this.id)" id="submitId">Click</button>
```